# Ajax success: function(data) is undefined

Tags: ajax, json

Edit: could've researched better... reading this post now: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call?lq=1)

I have an ajax request which returns JSON data.  When I watch it in fiddler, it does go out to the service and get the JSON data, but when I try to set a variable to it's response, that variable is "undefined".  If I `alert` in the success method, it alerts, but the variable is still undefined.

I tried changing the `function(data)` to `function(something)` incase that had anything to do with it... same story.

```
var returndata
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "GetSecurables/",
    data: { etaNumber: etaNumber },
    success: function (data) {
        returndata = data; //undefined
        alert('haaalp');
    }
});
```

The JSON is like below

```
[
  {
    "DelegateSid":null,
    "DisplayName":"Tom",
    "HasDelegation":true,
    "HasEtaManagement":false
  },
  {
    "DelegateSid":null,
    "DisplayName":"Tim",
    "HasDelegation":true,
    "HasEtaManagement":false
  },
  {
    "DelegateSid":null,
    "DisplayName":"Jake",
    "HasDelegation":true,
    "HasEtaManagement":false
  },
  {
    "DelegateSid":null,
    "DisplayName":"Ryan",
    "HasDelegation":true,
    "HasEtaManagement":false
  }
]
```

Comment: what is your code in "GetSecurables"?

Comment: Maybe because you didn't specifiy dataType : json

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var returndata;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "GetSecurables/",
    data: { etaNumber: etaNumber },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        returndata = data; 
        console.log(returndata);
    }
});
```

If the 2 outputs are the same it might be the case that you're trying to access `returndata` from outside its scope, hence the `undefined`, or that you're accessing `returndata` before the Ajax call completes.